# Not getting the required ASP.Net web API method while calling from Angular

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular

I am working on project in which I want to add a value to an Oracle database and get value from it. I am using Angular 4 using VSCode and ASP.NET Web API using Visual Studio 2015 for services.

My Angular code is working well and Web API code also working while calling from browser but when I call same method from Angular its not htting. Its hit the constructor but it's not hitting the required method in the ASP.NET Web API while calling. Kindly suggest what I have to do.... Help would be appriciated. My API code is this:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomer( UserInfo user )
{
    // int result;

    // result = _customerManager.SaveCustomer(user);
    // if (result > 0)
    // {
    //    return Ok(result);
    // }
    // else
    // {
    //    return NotFound();
    // }
    return null;
}
```

My service code is this:

```
register(userInfo: any) {
    debugger; 

    var url1 = this.baseUrl;
    url1 += "api/Account/Register";

    return this._http.post(url1, userInfo);


};
```

And path is

```
BASE_API_URL: "http://localhost:12795/",
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `([FromBody] UserInfo user)` in your POST action?

Comment: please provide errors you might be getting in the network tab of the browser debugger you might be getting

Comment: Use your tools thoughtfully so that you never write anything like `(userInfo: any)`. If you cannot be bothered to conform to your own code style rules, adjust them (disable `--noImplicitAny`).

Comment: I suppose the controller is `Account` and the method you want to hit is `SaveCustomer`. In that case add a attribute to the top of your controller action `[Route("Register")]`

Comment: @mersocarlin yes i tried this one but same result

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sir i am using tool thoughtfuly. There is no error while i run the code ny browser and angular code from command line the main issue is that its not hitting th required method.

Comment: @IvanMladenov you supposed right and i implement the method you mentioned but unfortunatly its not hitting the target same resut

Comment: What response do you receive ?

Comment: Sir no error is there in console screen when i hit the target by browser it hit but at the same time with same url when i hit from angular it just hit its constructor and go back to the view

Comment: Check your network tab. What is the response for this request

Comment: Sir what  i have to check from network tab . i can check

Comment: I tell what i have to check in network tab.Sir  with due respect i am new here in .net thats why little bit guide will  matter and i ll be thankful to you

Comment: Find the request you are making, open it and click on the response. What does it say

Comment: <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyFirstApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>

Comment: Perameter which i passed giving the same value which i have given it

Comment: http://localhost:4200/?empname=&empno=&empsalary= this path is also right

Comment: i can share my code at you acount sir if it is possible

Comment: I would be very thankful to you for your favour

Comment: I think that path you mentioned is wrong - you should be hitting http://localhost:4200/api/Account/Register?empname=&empno=&empsalary=. I suspect that is why your request is returning the Html of your page rather than the response from your API.

Comment: sir thats my angular path the orignal path of my api when is send request than during debugging it is http://localhost/api/Account/register

Comment: Doesn't that mean that the Angular path is wrong? Your question states that the Angular call is failing.

Comment: @nick_w sir you are right my Angular call is failing.How can i takle it

Answer (score 0):

Try decorate your API functions and your constructor, e.g.

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller

public AccountController (...){

    ....
   [HttpPost, ActionName("Register")]
   public IHttpActionResult SaveCustomer([FromBody] UserInfo user ){}
}
```

Comment: Sorry decorate API functions is about Visual Studio 2017. In Visual Studio 2015 your function's name must be equal your call, that's if your url is api/Account/Register, the controller must be called **AcountController** and the function **Register**

Comment: Sir my functions name is absolutly equal to my call

Comment: Controller call the required apibut unfortunatleey when call from angular its dontcalll even my path is right

Comment: You had write public IHttpActionResult **SaveCustomer** ( UserInfo user )

Comment: Sir i have writed this one in my first project now i  change the group  and here now its name is IHttpActionResult Register